# Scheduler and cron expression

Tags: cron, apache-camel, scheduler

How can I make route which will be use cron expression?

I mean I want to do something like this:

```
from("scheduler://foo?period=CRONEXPRESSION").to(SOME_BEAN);
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

For simple scheduling cases, you can use the [Camel Timer](http://camel.apache.org/timer.html) component that is part of `camel-core` and therefore does not need any other dependencies.

If you need to use a Cron expression, you can use the Camel Quartz component. For both versions you have to add a dependency.

- If you want to use Quartz 1.x see: [Camel Quartz](http://camel.apache.org/quartz.html)
- If you want to use Quartz 2.x see: [Camel Quartz 2](http://camel.apache.org/quartz2.html)

*Addition due to comment from Claus Ibsen*

And there is also the [Camel Scheduler](http://camel.apache.org/scheduler.html) component that is part of `camel-core` and able to handle Cron expressions. You can configure it to use Quartz2, Spring or your own scheduler (depending on it you have to add the dependency).

```
from("scheduler://foo?scheduler=quartz2&scheduler.cron=[your expression]")
```

There are examples and more information on the linked documentation pages.

Comment: Yeah quartz is known for cron. But the scheduler component from camel-core can also use quartz2 or spring cron (simpler cron than maybe quartz).